# Can Riven's passive-enhanced auto-attacks crit, and what is the basis for critical strike damage?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm curious if Riven's passive-enhanced autos can critically strike, and if so, is does the critical bonus apply to the passive bonus damage, or is it more like Vayne's tumble where the bonus part does not get the critical damage modifier?

Answer (score 3):

Riven's passive acts like an on-hit effect (it appears as a 2nd number next to her auto-attack damage), and it cannot crit. The auto-attack itself can crit normally, but won't affect the bonus damage from the passive.